# python dynamic dictionary from XML

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a paragraph in XML file like this:

```
<p1:car>                           
    <p1:feature car="111" type="color">511</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="223" type="color">542</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="299" type="color">559</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="323" type="color">564</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="353" type="color">564</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="391" type="color">570</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="448" type="color">570</p1:feature>

    <p1:feature car="111" type="tires" unit="percent">511</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="223" type="tires" unit="percent">513</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="299" type="tires" unit="percent">516</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="323" type="tires" unit="percent">516</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="353" type="tires" unit="percent">518</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="391" type="tires" unit="percent">520</p1:feature>
    <p1:feature car="448" type="tires" unit="percent">520</p1:feature>
</p1:car>
```

**What I want:**

I am working with LXML and I am looping through every elements and attributes and willing to make dictionary dynamically in following manner:

```
{color:[(111,511),(223,542).....] tires:[(111,511),(223,542).....]}
```

**What I tried:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

a=[] #extract attributes and text to list
comp = defaultdict(list)

 #some code to access root element

for m in k.getchildren(): #this iterates through <p1:car> element
                a.append([m.get('type'), m.get('car'), m.text])
                comp[m[0]].append(m[1:])
```

After running this program i get this error:

```
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1098, in lxml.etree._Element.__getitem__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:47744)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: from what I can see, `m` probably lacks element [1]

Comment: @Pynchia Thank you for going through. you mean last line should be comp[m[1]].append(m[1:]) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace m variable with a[-1] in last line or (better) use some temporary variable for storing values:

```
for m in k.getchildren(): #this iterates through <p1:car> element
    record = [m.get('type'), m.get('car'), m.text]
    a.append(record)
    comp[record[0]].append(tuple(record[1:]))
```

Comment: can you tell me what does 'tuple' does here in last line and i also used another approach   `for i in a:
                    comp[i[0]].append(i[1:])` but its not working. making use of your code gives error  `'tuple' object is not callable`

Comment: It should construct a tuple from list (because your comp dict has lists of tuples as values). If you don't want tuples use just `append(record[1:])` to create a list of lists.
Although I don't know, why it isn't working, problem seems to be outside this code.

Comment: your code is absolutely fine. there is some problem in my program which is showing error when it comes to making tuple but else wise its fine. Thank you for your efforts. I shall mark it as accepted.